# Can I Commit LGPL3 Derivative Work To An Apache 2 Licensed Project?

Tags: apache-2.0, lgpl, derivative-works

I am using a helpful project that is licensed under the LGPL3.

I have taken some of the useful code out of it and refactored it into a wrapper class and would like to add it to an upstream project.

As I understand it, my refactored code would count as a derivative work.

However, the upstream project is licensed under Apache 2.0.

Does the LGPL license from the original project mean that I can't contribute the refactored code to the upstream project?

Comment: Amon does an excellent job analysing the legalities of this.  I would only add that the project may well have an opinion on whether they want non-Apache-licenced code to be part of their project, so I would also try to take their views on the subject before committing it.  Some projects that use permissive free licences can get quite militant about having their code remain permissively-free in its entirety.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your code is derived from the LGPLv3 code you are bound by that license – it is a copyleft license like the GPLv3, just with a linking exception. You do not have the right to license this code under the Apache 2 license.

While Apache 2 and LGPLv3 are compatible, license compatibility is a one-way street: you can include Apache 2 licensed code in a LGPLv3 project, but not LGPLv3 licensed code in a Apache 2 project.

But the LGPLv3 offers a linking exception: the license of linked code doesn't matter if the relevant LGPL terms are still complied with. For example, the Apache 2 licensed project could use your software as a dynamically linked library without any impact on licensing. However, when binaries of the Apache 2 licensed project are distributed it would have to be accompanied by the source code of your software.